# where are the git package installed on fedora?

Tags: git, fedora, smartgit

So, i am running fedora 26 and was trying to use smartgit instead of commandline. but during the setup it ask me to give it the "git executable" but im unsure of what it is and i can't find where git files is supposed to be.

im currently having git 2.13.6 installed, as per confirmed by `git version`

Comment: "git executable" is the commandline `git`. Most probably it's `/usr/bin/git`

Comment: If you can run `git version`, `type git` will reveal where that instance of `git` is installed. (If you have several, `type -a git` will show them all.)

Comment: thanks, i found it in bin. but now for some reason i can't update it after 2.13 even after deleting it and reinstalling it

Comment: If you're really running Fedora *26*, then I'd recommend upgrading -- it stopped receiving security updates more than 3 years ago, as far as I can tell. Otherwise, consider not connecting it to the internet.

Comment: do i need to do a backup of the data on my computer for that? @grdryn

Comment: »» where is the git package installed on fedora «« : `$ rpm -ql git` prints a file list in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

By `git` "executable" it probably means the program itself. You can find this by typing `which <program>` in the terminal will tell you where the executable (if there is one) for the program you are looking for. On Fedora, you can also check *if* you have a package installed by using `rpm -qa <package>`.

`which git` should echo something along the lines of `/usr/bin/git`, which is where the "executable" is.

That being said, Fedora uses a so-called "point-release" cycle which basically means that every 6 months, a new version is released. It has varied with almost every version of Fedora, but the last five versions of Fedora have had a life-cycle of 392 days and, upon EOL (end-of-life), they are no longer maintained. This means that the packages will be deprecated and they will *not receive security updates*!

I highly encourage you to back up anything of value and either update your system (if that's even possible from such an old version) to a current version or, better yet, do a clean install of the latest version. The latter is the best option, because they have implemented many new and great features that greatly enhances the experience, stability, security etc.
If you don't like updating your system as often, you could go with distros such as Debian (24-month release cycle), Ubuntu LTS (5 years) or even Arch (rolling release).

Sorry for the long (and somewhat off-topic) post, but I thought I'd give you a heads up because Fedora 26 is obsolete since mid-2018.